# SQL (Redshift) get start and end values for consecutive data in a given column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a table that has the subscription state of users on any given day. The data looks like this

```
+------------+------------+--------------+
| account_id |    date    | current_plan |
+------------+------------+--------------+
| 1          | 2019-08-01 | free         |
| 1          | 2019-08-02 | free         |
| 1          | 2019-08-03 | yearly       |
| 1          | 2019-08-04 | yearly       |
| 1          | 2019-08-05 | yearly       |
| ...        |            |              |
| 1          | 2020-08-02 | yearly       |
| 1          | 2020-08-03 | free         |
| 2          | 2019-08-01 | monthly      |
| 2          | 2019-08-02 | monthly      |
| ...        |            |              |
| 2          | 2019-08-31 | monthly      |
| 2          | 2019-09-01 | free         |
| ...        |            |              |
| 2          | 2019-11-26 | free         |
| 2          | 2019-11-27 | monthly      |
| ...        |            |              |
| 2          | 2019-12-27 | monthly      |
| 2          | 2019-12-28 | free         |
+------------+------------+--------------+
```

I would like to have a table that gives the start and end dats of a subscription.  It would look something like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| account_id | start_date |  end_date  | subscription_type |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+
|          1 | 2019-08-03 | 2020-08-02 | yearly            |
|          2 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-31 | monthly           |
|          2 | 2019-11-27 | 2019-12-27 | monthly           |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

I started by doing a `LAG` windown function with a bunch of `WHERE` statements to grab the "state changes", but this makes it difficult to see when customers float in and out of subscriptions and i'm not sure this is the best method.

```
lag as (
    select *, LAG(tier) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY date ASC) AS previous_plan
            , LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY date ASC) AS previous_plan_date
    from data
)
SELECT *
FROM lag
where (current_plan = 'free' and previous_plan in ('monthly', 'yearly'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I think a difference of row numbers works:

```
select account_id, current_plan, min(date), max(date)
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account_id order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by account_id, current_plan order by date) as seqnum_2
      from data
     ) d
where current_plan <> free
group by account_id, current_plan, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Comment: So this is super close to what i am looking for, but it has subscriptions that aren't over (and the user moved into Free) as ending on today.  For example there is a row for someone who started a subscription a week ago, and all their rows say "monthly", but they have an end date, even though their subscription isn't over.  Also, thanks for giving me the proper terminology for this type of problem

Comment: I guess to reword, i only want to see rows with starts and ends for people who move into "free" after a subscription

Comment: @metersk . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question.